# How to solve a query with case conditions returning null values?

Tags: sql, datatable, case

I dont usually post in this forum but I came up with a problem I cant seem to fix since I'm fair new with programming.

I'm having a case problem with a query for a Datatable that needs to select orders based on an order line and case conditions, example if the order took 3 or less days to complete, it will go to column 1, if it took 5 or more days, to column 2, and between 4 and 5 days to column 3.

I'm using ajax for the Datatable.

This is how the code looks

**Ajax code**

```
    $table = <<<EOT
     (
        SELECT ce.lineanegocio AS linea, COUNT(c.entity) AS qty, 
        DATE_FORMAT(c.date_creation,'%Y-%c') AS date_creation1,
        DATE_FORMAT(pe.date_creation,'%Y-%c') AS date_creation2,
        CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 3 AND ce.lineanegocio = '11' THEN 1
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 3 AND ce.lineanegocio = '15' THEN 2
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 3 AND ce.lineanegocio = '12' THEN 3
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 3 AND ce.lineanegocio = '20' THEN 4
        ELSE 5 END AS date_diff1,
        CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '11' THEN 6
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '15' THEN 7
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '12' THEN 8
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '20' THEN 9
        ELSE 10 END AS date_diff2,
        CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 3 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '11' THEN 11
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 3 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '15' THEN 12
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 3 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '12' THEN 13
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) > 3 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, c.date_creation, pe.date_creation) <= 5 AND ce.lineanegocio = '20' THEN 14
        ELSE 15 END AS date_diff3
        FROM llx_commande c
        INNER JOIN llx_commande_extrafields ce ON c.rowid = ce.fk_object
        INNER JOIN llx_pedidosestado_fechaestado pe ON c.rowid = pe.id_pedido
        WHERE (c.fk_statut = '9' OR c.fk_statut = '11') AND (pe.estado = '11' OR pe.estado = '9')
        GROUP BY linea
        ORDER BY qty DESC
     ) temp
    EOT;
```

**Datatable code**

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).ready(function() {
          var table = $('#lineapedidos').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                dom: '',
                "bInfo": false,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "getPedidos2.php",
                "columns": [
              { "data": 0 },
              { "data": 1 },
              { "data": 2 },
              { "data": 3 },
              { "data": 4 },
                ],
                columnDefs: [
                {
                  targets: [2, 3, 4],
                  render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    return type === 'display' ?
                      data + '%' :
                      data;
                    }
                  }
                ]
            } );

          } );
```

**How the table looks**

[image]

So the problem are the NULL values that show up in the table, in "linea negocio 11" it should say something like 50%, 35%, 15%.

If I have to bring any other information about this code please let me know. Thanks in advance!

PD: I made the cases separately with a coalesce since I read somewhere that it wont return a null result but it didnt do the trick

Comment: In your javascript you could do: `(data || '0') + '%'`  and produce a 0% in the table if you would prefer zero to `null`. Or you could use the `IsNULL` function in your sql query to produce some default value instead of `NULL`

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to have data from the database in the NULL fields but I feel thats quite hard using case, maybe I should try with if / else instead?

Comment: If you're getting `null` then either you have no data that fits that case or your query is flawed.

Comment: I edited both the code and the pic to see it more clearly, I'm getting only 1 valid result for every row, everything else comes as null, or in this case, for the numbers I added in the else conditions. I tried adding an "is not null" in the where clause and it works perfect but only for one column, not the rest. Its hard for me to recognize if its flawed or the data doesnt fit correctly.